# iOS 7 Pop-Overs For iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, interface-builder, popover

I'm trying to implement a popover in the app I'm working on for the iPhone. The popover will display a UITableView. What is the simplest way to create a popover for the iPhone? One that Apple won't reject from the App store?

Comment: You're free to construct your own custom popup view class (which is a view with a clear background that covers the entire screen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIPopoverController class cannot run on iPhone. I suggest to use third party frameworks such as:

[WYPopoverController](https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController)

[WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)

[PopoverView](https://github.com/runway20/PopoverView)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you I will check these out, I wish apple would allow this class to run on iPhones.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)

It's a generalized version of the UIPopoverViewController, adapted to work with iPhone

Answer (score 0):

UIPopover class does not support  for iPhone it was made for iPad so if want to add popover in iPhone try third party library FPPopover you can download the code and procedure from below link

https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover